# Parse Skype messages to invoke an event

Tags: api, skype

Is it possible to parse the Skype messages using Skype API? 
I would like to create a Skype plugin so that I can read a particular string posted by a user and invoke some actions/events based on the text entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Skype4COM you can handle messages by listening to MessageStatus events and check the status (cmsSending / cmsSent / etc).

If you are interested you may have a look in a [skype plugin I wrote (called Binboo)](https://github.com/adrianoc/binboo) which  does exactly what you want: it listen for skype messages and reacts for some specific text.

Current version of Binboo supports plugins also (for instance, I have two: one to interact with [Jira](https://github.com/adrianoc/binboo/tree/master/Binboo.Jira) and another one for [text translations](https://github.com/adrianoc/binboo/tree/master/Binboo.Language))

One of the limitations I could not overcome so far is changing the message being sent (I'm not saying it is not possible, just that I didn't find a way)

Best